# Singleton not working with XCTests - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xctest

I am writing a unit test for one of my utility method. This utility method internally fetch some values based on a property set on a singleton object. In my unit test, before I call this utility method, I am setting the session object value and print to confirm that it gets set:

```
- (void)testMyMethod {
   [MySession sharedSession].isTesting = true;
   NSLog(@"isTesting = %d", [MySession sharedSession].isTesting); // prints 1
   [myClassObj myMethod];
}
```

But inside my `myMethod`, `isTesting` never passes the `true` check:

```
- (void)myMethod {
   if ([MySession sharedSession].isTesting == true) { // this condition is always failing
        ... do something ...
   }
}
```

I have also printed the singleton object both in test and in actual method and verified that both are referring to same memory location.

Anyone has any clue as why this is happening so. Any direction/pointer/guidance is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this sorted out -

Observed that application module and tests module are separated modules and so I removed the singleton class `MySession` from my test target and simply imported the project in my test class and it worked all fine.

Comment: That's great to find! How did you import the project? I did it by going to Build Phases - Compile Sources and added the product in there.